# Trailing slash in drupal

Tags: drupal, url

Drupal by default does not allow trailing slash for pages and articles. Is it possible to allow trailing slash using a plugin?

Comment: why would you need it? trailing slash is not used for pages and articles; trailing slash, AFAIK, denotes a directory.

Comment: When you are moving an exisitng well optimized site to Drupal, you don't want to set a redirect for all the current url's ending with a trailing slash.

Comment: I see that several users migrating to Drupal face this problem. It is a pity that Drupal does not provide this feature by default :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could hack the [globalredirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module to reverse its logic -- add the trailing slash if its not there, leave it alone if it is.

Comment: The links added by Drupal do not have the trailing slash by default. Hence that will create an extra redirection for each pages having a trailing slash.

Comment: You'd have to hack the core url() function in common.inc.. I think thats realistically the only way you're going to accomplish getting the output to have the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Nikit this should be doable through webserver rewrites.

There are some discussions on it on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/160753). I would recommend heading over to freenode and asking on #drupal.

Comment: I am more interested in a solution that does not require hacking Drupal Core.

Comment: This would not involve hacking core. This involves mod_rewrite with Apache.

Comment: @markdorison, the second suggestion does discusses the hacks to the core (among other things). sorry for the confusion, i was a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing Slash module for Drupal 7:

http://drupal.org/project/trailing_slash

Might have a D6 version later.

Comment: I ended up not using Drupal, since it was an existing website. I will surely test it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [URL with trailing slash](http://www.bananatools.com/drupal/url-trailing-slash.html)

Comment: I want a solution for Drupal. `.htaccess` modification alone won't be sufficient.